# Apache Spark: Which data storage and data format to choose

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hbase, hadoop2

I'm going to write a sales analytics application with Spark. Therefore I get a delta-dataset every night with new sales data (the sellings of the day before). Later I want to realize some analytics like Association-Rules or popularity of products.

The sales data contains information about:

- store-id
- article-group
- timestamp of cash-point
- article GTIN
- amount
- price

So far I used a simple `.textFile` method and RDDs in my Applications. I heard something about DataFrame and Parquet, which is a table-like data format for text files, right? And what about storing the data once in a database (I have HBase installed in a Hadoop cluster) and later read this?

Can someone give a short overview of the different types of save-/load-possibilities in Spark? And give a recommendation what to use for this data?

The data-amount are actually about 6 GB, which represent data data for 3 stores for about 1 year. Later I will work with data of ~500 stores and time-period of ~5 years.

Comment: Parquet is a better format to work with as it is columnar and it is splittable. Compressed text files (csv) are not splittable. You can consider partitioning your data by dates/store id and store it in hdfs as parquet. Spark can write parquet using dynamic partitions. You can then use Impala or hive to query this data. Using partitions in your query is recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spark to process that data without any problem. You can read from a csv file as well(there's a library from databricks that supports csv). You can manipulate it, from an rdd your one step closer to turning it into a dataframe. And you can throw the final dataframe dirrectly into HBASE.
All needed documentation you can find here:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html
https://www.mapr.com/blog/spark-streaming-hbase

Cheers, 
Alex

Comment: Great, thank you! I'm already familiar with Spark RDDs and text (csv) files. I read that DataFrames are faster than RDDs, is this correct? And would I notice the speed difference with the amount of data I will work with later?

Comment: Interesting points here: http://de.slideshare.net/StampedeCon/choosing-an-hdfs-data-storage-format-avro-vs-parquet-and-more-stampedecon-2015 and http://www.adsquare.com/comparing-performance-of-spark-dataframes-api-to-spark-rdd/

Comment: Well, you need the dataframes for spewing them out to Hbase. As far as speed is concerned, never tested and RDD vs DF speedwise.

Comment: Take any benchmark with a grain of salt: https://0x0fff.com/spark-dataframes-are-faster-arent-they/